# SQL partially serializable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, locking, transaction-isolation

The high-level issue that we are trying to solve is to prevent duplicate records from a user-kicked-off ETL process, which calls a procedure for each row it is importing (this is a simplification and changing the design is not part of my question). So basically we have something like this (note that the table has about 20 columns):

> PROCEDURE ImportRow (  @p1, @p2, @p3 etc )
>
> IF NOT EXISTS
>   (SELECT 1
>   FROM TargetTable
>   WHERE col1 = @p1 AND col2 = @p2 AND col3 = @p3 etc)
>
> INSERT INTO TargetTable(col1, col2, col3...)
>   VALUES (@p1, @p2, @p3)

So obviously we have a race condition that if two people inadvertently run the same importer at the same time, we end up with duplicate records.

We are willing to use `SERIALIZABLE` to ensure that `IF NOT EXISTS` will prevent the second transaction from doing the insert...

> PROCEDURE ImportRow (  @p1, @p2, @p3 etc )
>
> SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
>
> IF NOT EXISTS
>   (SELECT 1
>   FROM TargetTable (UPDLOCK)
>   WHERE col1 = @p1 AND col2 = @p2 AND col3 = @p3 etc)
>
> INSERT INTO TargetTable(col1, col2, col3...)
>   VALUES (@p1, @p2, @p3)

...however, as you know, without a covering index, this will lock the entire table...

...and we can't add a covering index because we have 20 columns.

But the first two parameters/columns are basically an "importer id" and an "as-of date", so, really it would be okay to have only THAT be serializable.  In other words, prevent the same importer from being run more than once, i.e. have the locking granularity be between 'entire table' and 'row-by-row'.  Something like this:

> PROCEDURE ImportRow ( @importer, @asOfDate, @p3, @p4, @p5 etc )
>
> --lock down the importer
>   SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
>   SELECT 1
>   FROM TargetTable (UPDLOCK)
>   WHERE importer = @importer AND asOfDate = @asOfDate
>
> IF NOT EXISTS
>   (SELECT 1
>   FROM TargetTable (UPDLOCK)
>   WHERE importer = @importer AND asOfDate = @asOfDate AND col3 = @p3 AND col4 = @p4 AND col5 = @p5 etc)
>
> INSERT INTO TargetTable(importer, asOfDate, col3, col4, col5...)
>   VALUES (@importer, @asOfDate, @p3, @p4, @p5)

We have a covering index on importer and asOfDate, so only that should be locked down with serializable, while the rest of the table should be free and clear.  The problem is that now this obviously produces a slow, ugly result set from that first `SELECT` query.

So is there another way to do this "partial serializable"?  I was thinking of burning a temp table, but that's wasteful.

> SELECT 1
>   INTO #Ignored
>   FROM TargetTable (UPDLOCK)
>   WHERE importer = @importer AND asOfDate = @asOfDate

The only other thing I can think of would be to put importer/asOfDate in a separate table and giving that pair an id ('importerDateId'), and then use that importerDateId in TargetTable, i.e. to normalize it a bit more, but I'd like to avoid a schema change.

Comment: Why do you have 20 columns that uniquely identify a row? That seems wide to me...

Comment: We're basically importing Excel sheets from third parties which have no duplicate rows but no good key

Comment: I'm still dubious that you need all 20 columns to guarantee uniqueness. That said, have you looked at sp_getapplock? With it, you're essentially creating a user-defined semaphore. As long as all of your import processes obey it, you should be fine.